# How to change the list in list without change whole list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

For example:
`a = [[]]*50` I want only `a[2]` to change to `[2]`, but if I do `a[2] = [2]` all the list become to `[2]`, and I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = [[]]*50
>>> a
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],  
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> a[1] = [2]
>>> a
[[], [2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],  
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> a[2] = [2]
>>> a
[[], [2], [2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

I hope I understood you correctly :)

Comment: Not at all :)))